# Windows user: csv files not found

Tags: python, csv, file-not-found

I am trying to extract CSV files from 2 folders. The following code returns an error message:

> [Errno 2] File b'aws_hourly_20170501.csv' does not exist: b'aws_hourly_20170501.csv'

```
station = int(input("station number? "))
def Datastations (station,path): 
    filepaths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in listdir(path) if 
    f.endswith('.csv')]
    ***Selection of the station***
    df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths))
    return (df)

df1 = Datastations(station,"refdata/obs") 
df2 = Datastations(station,"refdata/BoM_ETA_20160501-20170430/obs")**
```

As I am using windows, I think that might be a syntax issue. Any idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's not related to Windows as such.

Here, you're doing

```py
filepaths = [f for f in listdir(path) if f.endswith('.csv')]
```

where, the `filepaths` list is just a list of names of csv files under that dir named `path`.

You should keep it as

```py
filepaths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in listdir(path) if f.endswith('.csv')]
```

This will make `filepaths` as the list of all files with their respective paths.

PS: Don't forget to import os module first

Comment: Thank you very much your fix worked perfectly well ! I am also trying to only concatenate data for a given weather station. station number is a specific column within my dataframe. Would you know a way to achieve this? It would start this way: `station = int(input("station number? "))` and then include the station selection in the code so that it returns a dataframe with fewer lines. In a different and slower version of this code, i called the station number with this: `df = df[df.station_number==station]` but i am not sure where to apply the selection in that case`

Comment: hi @GuillaumeRouja, I am not able to understand this query. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sure,@Siddhesh Suhas Sathe, I have edited the code above with the selection of the station. I would like to insert a line so i can only extract data for a specific station using something like `df = df[df.station_number==station]` so i don't need to concatenate all the data

Comment: in fact instead of using `map(pd.read_csv, filepaths)` & concatenate at the same time, i would like to add 1 step between to select the lines i want to concatenate because the running time is very long so i would like to concatenate less data if that makes sense.

Comment: The idea would be to have a code that basic does this: `df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths)) if df = df[df.station_number==station]` (i take the station as an argument asked to the user. it corresponds to the specific lines i want to concatenate within the 730 csv files)